# In Jsp,what's the difference between ${param.name} and ${param[name]}

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

In Jsp,what's the difference between `${param.name}` and `${param[name]}?`
I've tested that they can both get the parameter I set from a servlet,but I want to find out the difference between them.e.g,in what sittuaton,one can work while another one doesn't?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks,I just can't find the relevant information and think there may be a difference:)

Comment: If `name` is a String variable with the value `"name"`, there is no difference. If `name` is `"foo"`, then `${param[name]}` is the same as `${param.foo}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the following ways are evaluated same in standard JSP EL:

```
${param.myvar}
${param[name]}  // here `name` is another EL variable with value `name = "myvar"`
${param["myvar"]}
${param['myvar']}
```

If you're referring to a variable, then you can use 2nd one. Otherwise if you're directly accessing through value, then you can use 3rd or 4th one.

Comment: And therefore there *is* a difference, since #2 is different. You even said so yourself in the comment.

Comment: Thanks for notifying @Andreas. I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According JSP specification:

> > The EL follows ECMAScript in unifying the treatment of the **.** and [] operators.
> >     
> >     expr-a.identifier-b is equivalent to expr-a["identifier-b"]; that is, the identifier
> >     identifier-b is used to construct a literal whose value is the identifier, and then the []
> >     operator is used with that value.